# MySQL flags in dumps

Tags: mysql

Looking at a mySQL Dump, I have come across something and like to know what they are.

I see:

```
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xxx` */;
```

What is the flag 50001, is there a list of what they mean?

Answer (score 21):

It is discussed on the MySQL's forums/mailing lists [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,431053,431068#msg-431068).

> ```
> /*!50001 DROP TABLE `category_count_view`*/;
> ```
>
> This is a "feature" of MySQL. Any other RDBMS will treat this as a
>   comment.
>
> But, MySQL looks at 50001 and checks that as a MySQL version. This is
>   Version 5.00.01, or 5.0.1 in the real world, but leaves room for the
>   the sub-version and release to be greater than 9.
>
> MySQL will treat the line as a comment if MySQL is below 5.0.1, and
>   will process the line if MySQL is greater than or equal to 5.0.1.
>
> It's a way making a SQL script compatible with different versions of
>   MySQL, and allows new features to be included.

Answer (score 4):

The 500001 is regarding the MySQL version that generated the file.

This would be  5.00.01 or 5.0.01

Answer (score 3):

50001 is a value that indicate your mysql version.

This is Version 5.00.01, or 5.0.1 in the real world, but leaves room for the the sub-version and release to be greater than 9.

It's a way making a SQL script compatible with different versions of MySQL, and allows new features to be included.

Comment: If its the version, whats
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`YYY` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

Comment: 32312 is similar, but the version of the mysql server