# mysqldump without "CREATE ALGORITHM" and "DEFINER"

Tags: mysql, database-backups

In my database backups and export I get something like the following:

```
/*!50001 DROP TABLE `vTime`*/;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `vTime`*/;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`db_user`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `vTime` AS select ... */;
```

1. This causes problems when restoring since the "CREATE ALGORITHM" and "DEFINER" parts fail when trying to restore.  Is there a way to make `mysqldump` just do a simple `CREATE VIEW` instead?
2. Bonus question: what do the `/*!50001` parts mean?

**EDIT:** I should add that this is the error I'm getting:

`#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

**EDIT 2:** It appears that only the `/*!50013 DEFINER=` part is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /*!50001 part is a version number.

The question was already answered here: [MySQL flags in dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855862/mysql-flags-in-dumps)

The main issue of removing the DEFINER is best done with a script. Some examples already online:

https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/removing-definer-from-mysql-dump/

[Remove DEFINER clause from MySQL Dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps)

Answer (score 2):

This sed command should work for removing both these clauses from mysqldump -

```
sed -e 's|^/[*]!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED [*]/|/*!50001 CREATE */|' -e '/^[/][*]!50013 DEFINER=/d'
```

Where 50001 and 50013 are respective versions as already mentioned above.